# What does time mean in respective of photons?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, time, time-dilation

Because as we approach the speed of light, time gets slower for us so for a photon traveling at "*speed of light*" wouldn't the time become "*0*" or like *stopped*, yet it takes time for light to travel.

also as light would travel some distance in some given time, for a photon time is really *non-existent* thus how do we know that it even travels or not. Or would time get -ve after the speed of light?

I'm so sorry if this sounds confusing, but it's been bothering me for a while now. I would be pleased to be corrected, thanks in advance!!

Comment: "Because as we approach the speed of light, time gets slower for us..." No, it doesn't.

Comment: @hft then can u please explain time dilation to me?

Comment: No, that is too broad a question for this forum. It is explained in introductory physics textbooks such as Halliday Resnick.

Comment: like can u explain why doesn't it fit here in this question?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We have several Q&As about how photons "experieince" time.  It's not a trivial question and it's a hard one to answer without getting quite technical.

Comment: Thank you @StephenG-HelpUkraine  very cool!